# How to check Pandas cell value is nan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am getting value of cell as `nan`, But when I do `cell_value == np.nan` then it's False.

Then I tried to print `type(cell_value)` it's giving `<class 'float'>`

How do I match it ?

Comment: Have you looked at [pandas.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) method?

Comment: it will work for dataframe not for single value.

Comment: Sorry I got answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use equality on `nan`, you can evaluate it as follows:

```
np.isnan(np.nan)
#returns True

pd.isnull(np.nan)
#returns True

np.nan == np.nan
#Always returns False
```

Because `nan` is a special floating point value.